# C - Loop won't break

Tags: c, string, loops

I want the loop to break when "Enter" is pressed.  Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define len 20
#define limit 100

//Prototypes for functions
int read_word(char str[], int n);



int main(void)
{
  char *p;
  char word[len+1];
  int i=0, nwords = 0;

//Loop for reading in words and allocating an array 
  for (;;)
   {
      if (nwords == limit)
       {
          printf("Insufficient Space\n");
          break;
       }
      printf("Enter word: ");
      scanf("%c", &word);
      p = (char*) malloc(nwords*sizeof(char));
      p[i]= read_word(word, len);
      i++;

      if (p == NULL)
      {
          printf("Insufficient Space\n");
          break;
      }
  }

  for(i=0; i<nwords; i++)
      printf(" %s\n", p[i]);

  return 0;

  } 
int read_word(char str[], int n)
{
  char ch; 
  int i = 0;

  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
      if (i<n)
          str[i++] = ch; 
  str[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Where do you test for a press of the Enter key?

Comment: You are also checking the `p` pointer for `NULL` too late - after using it.

Comment: I believe it's in the read_word function. Should be the controlling expression for the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scanf` call reads the first character, and then your `read_word` function overwrites it. If the `scanf` call reads the newline, it will then be ignored.

The lines:

```
  p = (char*) malloc(nwords*sizeof(char));
  p[i]= read_word(word, len);
```

... also appears wrong. `read_word` returns an integer (the length of the string read), but you are storing into a `char` array. Also, you are re-allocating the memory for `p` each time through the loop, so the values stored previously will be lost.

To fix:

- change `p` to be an `int *`, and initialize it to null
- change the `malloc` call to a suitable `realloc`
- remove the call to `scanf` entirely
- move the check for `p == null` *before* the assignment of `p = (char*) malloc(nwords*sizeof(char));'

Or: is `p` meant to actually be an array of strings (the words themselves) rather than the word length? In that case you have to:

- change `p` to be an `char **`
- change the allocation size (for the `realloc` call) to `nwords * sizeof(*p)`
- allocate (using `malloc`) storage for each word instead of having `word` be a stack-allocated array
- set `p[i] = word;` rather than the current assignment.

Comment: So by changing p to an array of int pointers, I will be able to store the the strings into the element and then increment the pointer to access it?

Comment: Yes I want to store the words as strings into an array and then be able to access the individual words

Comment: @Richard, no. To store a string into an element, the element type should be `char *` (or `char[]`). See the last part of my (edited) answer.

Comment: @Richard then you need to change p to be a `char **`, i.e. a pointer to strings, not a pointer to chars. Also note you still need to remove the call to `scanf`, change the existing `malloc` to `realloc`, and move the null pointer check.